# popen doesn't run a proces

Tags: php, exec, popen

I have a function that should run a process in background

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen('start /B '.$cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

I try to run script

```
$cmd = "php ..\runffmpeg.php";
execInBackground($cmd);
```

But it does nothing. When I try to run

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 video_out.avi';
execInBackground($cmd);
```

Its all right. And when I try to run

```
exec("php ..\runffmpeg.php");
```

It's also all right.
So, pclose(popen('start /B php ..\runffmpeg.php', "r")); doesn't run a command. Whats a problem?
I'm using Windows and php 5.4.7

Comment: U got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `$cmd= include("php ..\runffmpeg.php");`

Comment: No, I cann't becaus it should run in background.

Answer (score 0):

hmm; forget process mgmt and just popen() the resource.
If it is a daemon, you get access to it, else a subprocess is created/destroyed with the popen()/pclose().